# How to validate hiddenfor fields in asp.net mvc razor views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a jQuery `selectable` widget in my razor view which displayed as an `<ol>` and updated from a comma separated string in SQL Server table just like below:

```
<ol class="ui-selectable" style="width:auto" id="selectable1">

@{
    var color = Model.AvailableColors.Split(',');
    foreach (var clr in color)
        {
          <li class="btn red-mint" style="margin: 10px 0">@clr</li>
        }
 }
 </ol>
```

The above as mentioned displays set of colors like (Red, Green, Purple and etc) list which is of-course `selectable` and the user can only pick one from the list at a time.
I passed the selected list item value in a hidden field which is then passed to controller action method with below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectable1").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ci) {
                $(ci.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
                $("#selectedcolor").val($("#selectable1>li.ui-selected").html());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

In my form I've a `HiddenFor` razor attribute to pass selected list item value to the controller as below:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AvailableColors, new { @id = "selectedcolor" })
```

Now here is something that I am stuck and couldn't find a solution searching over internet. I want that if no item selected the validation should occur and the validation message for the `AvailableColors` should appear but I have no idea how to do it. Any help please?
**EDIT:** Here is the controller action method that I am passing data to:
// GET: /Store/AddToCart/5

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id,int SelectedQuantity,  string SelectedSizes, string AvailableColors)
{
    // Retrieve the album from the database
    var addedProduct = dbContext.Products
        .Single(product => product.ProductID == id);

    // Add it to the shopping cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    cart.AddToCart(addedProduct, SelectedQuantity, AvailableColors,SelectedSizes);

    // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider adding a new property to store the selected item text(string) in your view model and decorate it with `[Required]` data annotation.

```
public class AddToCartViewModel
{
  public int ProductId { set;get;}

  [Required]
  public int SelectedQuantity { set;get;}

  [Required]
  pubilc string SelectedColor { set;get;}

  // Add other properties as needed.
}
```

and have this hidden form in your form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","ShoppingCart"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(f => f.SelectedColor)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(f=>f.SelectedColor)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
}
```

When you submit the form `ModelState.IsValid` will be false and if you return the model back to view, you will see the error message for `SelectedColor`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(AddToCartViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //continue saving and return something
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

If you have client side unobtrusive validation, It won't work with hidden field by default. One workaround you can do is to keep the field as an input, but set the visibility to hidden. Then the client side validation will also show the validation error message.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","ShoppingCart"))
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.SelectedColors, new {style="visibility:hidden;"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(f=>f.SelectedColor)
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that I am passing the value to another controller ?

Comment: Just use the other overload of HTML.BeginForm which takes a controller  name and action name to build the form action attribute value.

Comment: You mean this way? `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductID }))`, still not working.

Comment: You should add those properties to your view model (with needed `Required` data annotation and use that as the parameter for your httppost action method(like i showed in the answer) so that you can make use of model validation framework to validate the values. See the updated answer.

Comment: Shyju is definitely correct.  I just wanted to add that it doesn't make see for validation on a hidden field because you are the only person who can actually set that value.

Comment: Thanks for your help appreciated, just want to know how can I show the validation message above the `<ol>` ordered list?

Comment: Move the call to Html.ValidationMessageFor(thus the gnerated html needed to show the validation errors) to wherever you want

Comment: thanks for clariyfing the situation wthen using client side validation.